# How to specify multiple type in schema model in kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo Grid and I am specifying its type in schema model.

Below is my schema model

```
schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            UOMName: { type: "string" },
                            ConversionFactor: { type: "string" },
                        }
                    }
}
```

I want ConversionFactor type to be string for one scenario and number for another scenario .

Is there any way where i can specify more than one type in kendo schema model ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify two different [`schema`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema)'s for the same Kendo UI DataSource. What you can do is have two separate (and almost identical) DataSource instances, and switch between them when needed, via the [`setDataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setDataSource) method.

```
var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({ /* ... */ });
var dataSource2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({ /* ... */ });

// create the Grid with the first dataSource
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource1
});

// some time later, switch to the second dataSource
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(dataSource2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . Will try to follow